# Programmatically get a list on installed composer modules

Tags: php, composer-php

I am looking for a way to get a list of installed composer modules in my application. Is there something like `\Composer->getModules()` that can be used? I also would like to get other values from the composer.json file like type of package and things. The goal of what I am trying to achieve is composer including modules into my framework and have the application automatically know they are there without any other installation.

Comment: Just read the contents of `composer.json` or `composer.lock`?

Comment: I would have to read each modules composer.json to get values set in each module. Also, just for a note, reading your composer.json does not display all installed modules because of how dependencies are managed. Child dependencies won't be listed in composer.json but still installed.

Comment: Reading the `composer.lock` will give me all installed modules but will still require me to read in each composer.json from the modules in order to get values set in each of the `composer.json` under `config` or other sections.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with some iterators to get a list of composer `required` packages. Create a file in the root of your project (where `vendor` resides) then add the below code snippet. This looks for all `composer.json` files within `vendor` directory or root (and not ones from other directories like `src`):

```
function getComposerPackages() {
    $directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./');
    $regexIterator = new RegexIterator(
        new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator),
        '~^.(.)(?:vendor\1.*)?composer\.json$~',
        RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH
    );

    $requiredModules = [];
    foreach ($regexIterator as $filePath) {
        $jsonContent = file_get_contents($filePath[0]);
        $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonContent, true);
        if (isset($jsonArray['require'])) {
            $requiredModules += $jsonArray['require'];
        }
    }

    return $requiredModules;
}

print_r(getComposerPackages());
```

The output is similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [aoepeople/scheduler] => v1.6.13
    [nwdthemes/revslider] => dev-master
    [churiart/blogomatic] => dev-master
    [php-pm/php-pm] => v1.0.4
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: This brings a different approach to the step before my problem. Instead of declaring where the registration file is in your `composer.json` I could just iterate over a `app/` and `vendor/`, looking for files that match the pattern `*/*/etc/config.yaml`. If found, add to an array of available registration files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an adaptation of @revo's answer

```
function getComposerPackages() {
    $requiredModules = [];
    foreach( glob("vendor/*/*/composer.json") as $filePath ) {
        $jsonContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonContent, true);
        if (isset($jsonArray['require'])) {
            $requiredModules += $jsonArray['require'];
        }
    }
    return $requiredModules;
}

print_r(getComposerPackages());
```